# Sharepoint Branding

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to brand share point. I have created a mastepage in the top level site. I have soem controls in there which I have overridden. When I apply the master page onto other sites my custom controls do not display but the default ones's do. Any idea what might be going wrong>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a copy of a working OOTB master page and be sure to include all the contentplaceholders in your new one. If you don't you'll have problems. Stay away from so-called minimal master page downloads being offered online.

As for your custom controls, deploy them as a Feature and activate it on the WFE. Include your customizations in a Feature also.